# How to give access different object of a model to different users in django by the creator of the object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a classroom project and I am completely new to Django. How to modify my models (course,user) so that I can add students to the course in two ways
1)By entering the class code by students.
2)By sending join invitations to students from a list of all students by selecting some by the teacher and if the student confirms/accepts he will be added.

i am attaching the models below

**user model**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Course Model**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course_sec = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(25)])
    classroom_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug=models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.classroom_id)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_valid(self):
        pass
```

**Teacher Views**

```
@login_required
def teacher_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = add_course(request.POST or None)
    context = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        course = form.save(commit=False)
        course.created_by = request.user
        course.save()
        messages.success(request, "Class Created Sucessfully")
        return redirect('/tdashboard')
    context['add_courses'] = form
    return render(request, 'teacherview.html', context)

@login_required
def view_courses(request, *args, **kwargs):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
    dict = {'course': courses}
    return render(request, 'teacherhome.html', dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

create a many2many relationship between the courses and students. Then you can do course.add(student) when a student has the right invitation code. Is this what you want?

use the groups in django

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

my_group = Group.objects.get(name='my_group_name') 

my_group.user_set.add(your_user)
```

so you have two groups students and teachers

Comment: yes... can you tell me how can I modify my models to add students to the course? i am new to django . @saro

Comment: cant write out the whole code, but this is a start. create a teacher model and a student model. Or use the groups option in django. make a many2many relatioship between those models and the course model. If you do that than you can add the teachers en students to a course. Per course you can create a random nmbr as invitation code, if student typs in the right number correponding with the course do course.add(student). Everything above is very well documented iff you put some effort in it

Comment: can u give me an example of a teacher/student model ? what field do I need to include and how will I differentiate between teacher and student? tia @saro

Comment: take a look at the docs, they are good to follow
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: i understand the add part but i am not understanding how will I differentiate between student and teacher? @saro

Comment: see my updated answer